# How to delete images with the low pixel value in a folder

Tags: python, numpy

I have some problems with removing images in a folder

The followings are what I have done.

```
import os,glob
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

path = "/Users/Xin/Desktop/SVM-Image-Classification-master/Folder"
# Delete images with the low pixel value
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    images = Image.open(os.path.join(path,filename))
    print(images)
    print(np.mean(images))
    pirnt(os.listdir(path))
    if np.mean(images) < 10:
        os.listdir(path).remove(filename)
print(os.listdir(path))
```

I expected that the images with the low pixel value can be deleted. However, the result presented as follow, the image that I want to delete is still in the list.

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x256 at 0x1C19FE37F0>
9.507644653320312
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x256 at 0x1C198F2E10>
10.004150390625
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x256 at 0x1C19FE37F0>
10.897491455078125
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x256 at 0x1C198F2F98>
10.406112670898438
['0543_AD_axial_090_PET.jpg', '0543_AD_axial_091_PET.jpg', '0543_AD_axial_093_PET.jpg', '0543_AD_axial_092_PET.jpg']
```

Can anyone give me a help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are just removing the filename from the temporary list created by `os.listdir(path)`. If you want to remove the file completely from disk, you need to use `os.remove`.

For example:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    images = Image.open(os.path.join(path,filename))
    if np.mean(images) < 10:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
```